# Whether require and use are similiar in php?

Tags: php, ringcentral

use `RingCentral\SDK;`

or

```
require('/home/developer/workspace/ringcentral/demo/SDK.php');
```

Instead of using 'use' - php 5.6 command ,it is better to use require - php 5.3 ?

SDK class file contains following code

```
class SDK
{

const VERSION = '0.5.0';

/** @var Platform */
protected $platform;

/** @var Context */
protected $context;

public function __construct($appKey, $appSecret, $server)
{

    $this->context = new Context();

    $this->platform = new Platform($this->context, $appKey, $appSecret, $server);

}

public function getPlatform()
{
    return $this->platform;
}

public function getSubscription()
{
    return new Subscription($this->context, $this->platform);
}

public function getContext()
{
    return $this->context;
}

}
```

Comment: `use` and `require` is totally different thing.

Comment: require() loads a script. The use command is to help with namespacing. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: I m working in PHP 5.3 ,so i could not use 'use' . can u say the alternative for  'use'?

Comment: You can't use `use` in `PHP 5.3`. Because this feature is added in `PHP 5.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **require** an autoloader to allow SPL autoload to resolve **use** statements:

```
// if you use Composer
require('vendor/autoload.php');
// or just require a PHAR
require('path-to-sdk/ringcentral.phar');

use RingCentral\SDK\SDK;

$sdk = new SDK(...);
```

You actually may omit use statement and use fully-qualified class name:

```
$sdk = new RingCentral\SDK\SDK(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

`require()` is used to require another file while `use` is used to use a class from another namespace, so those both commands are totally different and not comparable.

In your case you will need to use `require()` unless you are using any kind of autoloading like `composer` to make the class available in your file.